# How would I append the data I have extracted from a file using the current python code

Tags: python, database, list, append

new to python here.
I am trying to extract certain sections that has display bitcoin prices. I want to only show me the prices after reading the rest of the file contents. I'm stuck with this current code

```
sentences = []
words_count = 0
word = input("Enter word: ")
count  = 0
# file containing words and numbers
with open('data.txt') as file:
for line in file:
    words = line.split()
    words_count += len(words)
    sentences.append(line)
for line in sentences:
    if word in line:
        btc = (line[13:21])
        print(btc)
        count += 1
    else:
        count == 0
        print('Not found')
print(count, 'lines contain', word)
```

Comment: you need to indent the body of `with open...`

Comment: You need to show a sample of the file.

Comment: In the second `for` loop, `line` is a list of words, not a string. Are you sure `line[13:21]` is really what you want?

Comment: Don't print `Not found` in the `else:` block. The word might be found in a different line. At the end of the loop, print `Not found` if `count` is still `0`.

Comment: `count == 0` doesn't do anything when it's used as a statement. You need to use it in a conditional statement like `if`, e.g. `if count == 0: print("Not found")`

Comment: `else:` is useless. It will run code on every line which doesn't have `word`. You should use `if cound == 0` after `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand what you want to do but ...

- you have wrong indentations,
- you should check `count == 0` after `for`-loop
- if you want to print prices after `line contain` then you should keep them on list and use `for`-loop after `line contain` to display them

```
word = input("Enter word: ")

# --- read lines from file ---

sentences = []
words_count = 0

with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        words_count += len(words)
        sentences.append(line)

# --- work with lines ---

count  = 0
prices = []

for line in sentences:
    if word in line:
        btc = line[13:21]
        #print(btc)
        prices.append(btc)
        count += 1
            
# - after loop -

if count == 0:
    print('Not found')
else:
    print(count, 'lines contain', word)
    for btc in prices:
        print(btc)
```

---

**EDIT:**

In this example you don't have to use `count += 1` but after loop use `count = len(prices)`